# AngularJS: special ng-if for directive to be applied / not applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have a block

```
<div class="myclass" mydirective="mycontrol.param">
</div>
```

that is repeatable (used) several times (but different by different parameters) in another directive.

I need to add the conditional to `mydirective` so it is persists in the block based on kind of ng-if `true` or `false` values for it.

What's the way to make it done?

P.S. What actually `mydirective` does is adds some DOM elemenets into the div it belongs to.

Comment: Can you provide source code for that directive?